# Is it okay for holiday-makers to enter the United Kingdom with a single ticket?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, vacations

People's vacation plans may change. Getting a single airline ticket is better than getting a return ticket in such situations.

The potential visitors have just received their new United Kindgom general visitor visa. They also have a previous history of a short holiday in the United Kingdom last year. The visitors would be able to show substantial funds, investments and property in their home country; and therefore reasons to return to their home country, India, within eight weeks.

Would it be okay for the holiday-makers to enter the United Kingdom with a single ticket?

Comment: @GayotFow Post as an answer?

Comment: Thanks @GayotFow for the information. If anyone posts an answer, I'm happy to upvote / mark it as correct.

Comment: @SumanKrishnaSaha, your offer went 18 hours unanswered, so allow me to have a chance :)

Comment: Surely it'd be cheaper to get a return and just pay the administration charge to change the return flight than it would be to pay for two single tickets

Comment: For intercontinental flights, purchasing a flexible return ticket is likely to be cheaper than buying two singles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Travelling to the UK without nailing down an onward journey is a poor idea.

Some background...

Having an entry clearance basically implies that you have successfully completed your landing interview *before you even arrived* in the UK.  [Paragraph 25A of the rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423556/20150424_immigration_rules_part_1_final.pdf) makes this clear...

> An entry clearance which satisfies the requirements set out in article
>   3 of the Immigration (Leave to Enter and Remain) Order 2000 will have
>   effect as leave to enter the United Kingdom. The requirements are that
>   the entry clearance must specify the purpose for which the holder
>   wishes to enter the United Kingdom and should be endorsed with the
>   conditions to which it is subject or wish a statement that it has
>   effect as indefinite leave to enter the United Kingdom. The holder of
>   such an entry clearance will not require leave to enter on arrival in
>   the United Kingdom and, for the purposes of these Rules, will be
>   treated as a person who has arrived in the United Kingdom with leave
>   to enter the United Kingdom which is in force but which was given to
>   him before his arrival.

It means they already know you and all your details and you have been "cleared" to enter the UK without further ado.  So your landing interview will be shorter and more structured than for say, Americans.

HOWEVER, they need to check your documents for forgeries and alterations; and they are entitled to ask about your plans for this particular visit (if they want to).

> Evidence of an onward journey is also important. While a return ticket
>   is no guarantee that a passenger will leave the UK, a single ticket
>   will often trigger further questions. If passengers have a return
>   ticket that is open, or dated after the time they claim to be leaving
>   the country, this casts doubt on their true intentions.

Source: Home Office Report:  [*Exploring the decision making of Immigration Officers: a research study examining non-EEA passenger stops and refusals at UK ports*](http://www.statewatch.org/news/2007/jan/uk-ho-immig-decision-making-study.pdf)

What they are saying is that if they want to see your onward journey and you do not have one, you will be in ***trouble***, *despite having an entry clearance*.  In the current era and public mood, it means your entry clearance will be cancelled and the IO will issue removal instructions.  It is not a guaranteed outcome, nothing is guaranteed where an IO's discretionary latitude is concerned, but it is playing with fire, ill-advised, and wildly adventurous.

For completeness, I have to mention that it's avoidable if you are known as a [high net worth individual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-net-worth_individual) (HNWI) or a known public figure or if your passport is wallpapered with previous entry clearances etc etc.  In those cases the odds are improved.